# Terraform output not found in Module

Tags: terraform

I'm getting the following error running `Terraform apply` when trying to reference an output from another Module:

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on ../app-db-modules/rds.tf line 14, in resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "ccDBSubnetGroup":
│   14:   subnet_ids = ["${data.terraform_remote_state.remote.outputs.ccPrivateSubnetId}"]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.terraform_remote_state.remote.outputs is object with no attributes
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "ccPrivateSubnetId".
╵
```

**Tree**

```
.
├── app
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfstate
│   └── terraform.tfstate.backup
├── app-db-modules
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── rds.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── app-network-modules
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── outputs.tf
│   ├── variables.tf
│   └── vpc.tf
└── app-tf-state-infra-modules
    ├── main.tf
    ├── tf-state-infra.tf
    └── variables.tf
```

**main.tf** (app dir)

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "MY_BUCKET_NAME"
    key            = "tf-infra/terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    dynamodb_table = "terraform-state-locking"
    encrypt        = true
  }

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~>3.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

...

module "vpc-infra" {
  source = "../app-network-modules"

  # VPC Input Vars
  vpc_cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
  public_subnet_cidr = "10.0.0.0/24"
  private_subnet_cidr = "10.0.1.0/24"
}

module "rds-infra" {
  source = "../app-db-modules"

  # RDS Input Vars
  db_az = "us-east-1a"
  db_name = "ccDatabaseInstance"
  db_user_name = var.db_user_name
  db_user_password = var.db_user_password
}
```

**vpc.tf** (app-network-modules)

```
...
resource "aws_subnet" "ccPrivateSubnet" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.ccVPC.id
    cidr_block = var.private_subnet_cidr
}
...
```

**outputs.tf** (app-network-modules)

```
output "ccPrivateSubnetId" {
  description = "Will be used by rds Module to set subnet_ids"
  value = aws_subnet.ccPrivateSubnet.id
}
```

The following `{data.terraform_remote_state.remote.outputs.ccPrivateSubnetId}` is causing the error:

**rds.tf** (app-db-modules)

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "remote" {
  backend = "s3"

  config = {
    bucket  = "MY_BUCKET_NAME"
    key     = "tf-infra/terraform.tfstate"
    region  = "us-east-1"
  }
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "ccDBSubnetGroup" {
  subnet_ids = ["${data.terraform_remote_state.remote.outputs.ccPrivateSubnetId}"]
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "ccDatabaseInstance" {
  db_subnet_group_name = "ccDBSubnetGroup"
  availability_zone   = var.db_az 
  allocated_storage   = 20
  storage_type        = "standard"
  engine              = "postgres"
  engine_version      = "12.5"
  instance_class      = "db.t2.micro"
  name                = var.db_name
  username            = var.db_user_name
  password            = var.db_user_password
  skip_final_snapshot = true
}

output "all_outputs" {
  value = data.terraform_remote_state.remote.outputs
}
```

Any thoughts on why `data.terraform_remote_state.remote.outputs is object with no attributes` and/or why I'm unable to reference the `ccPrivateSubnetId` in `rds.tf` which was provided as output from another Module (`vpc.tf`) would be appreciated!

---

**EDIT**ing to provide solution based on comments provided below.

**main.tf**

```
...
module "vpc-infra" {
  source = "../app-network-modules"

  # VPC Input Vars
  vpc_cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
  public_subnet_cidr = "10.0.0.0/24"
  private_subnet_cidr = "10.0.1.0/24"
}

module "rds-infra" {
  source = "../app-db-modules"

  # RDS Input Vars
  ccPrivateSubnetId = "${module.vpc-infra.ccPrivateSubnetId}"
  db_az = "us-east-1a"
  db_name = "ccDatabaseInstance"
  db_user_name = var.db_user_name
  db_user_password = var.db_user_password
}
...
```

**outputs.tf**

```
output "ccPrivateSubnetId" {
  description = "Will be used by RDS Module to set subnet_ids"
  value = "${aws_subnet.ccPrivateSubnet.id}"
}
```

**vpc.tf**

```
...
resource "aws_subnet" "ccPrivateSubnet" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.ccVPC.id
    cidr_block = var.private_subnet_cidr
}
...
```

**rds.tf**

```
resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "ccDBSubnetGroup" {
  subnet_ids = ["${var.ccPrivateSubnetId}"]
}
...
```

Comment: You're mixing module output and remote state references and it's a bit odd in my opinion. I'd expect the output from the network module to be passed back into the database module. And only reference the remote state in a different context entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @9bO3av5fw5 . I'm just learning Terraform (literally just started looking at it earlier this week), so I didn't realize what I'm doing is bad practice. Would you happen to have a reference I can use to follow your suggestion?

Comment: Your edit probably should be an answer really. That looks much more 'normal' to me. Note if on latest terraform you should be able to do `[var.ccPrivateSubnetId]` rather than `["${var.ccPrivateSubnetId}"]` unless I've missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.terraform_remote_state` in general is bad practice. I would call it a very advanced feature that should only be used in extreme edge cases. If you are referencing the same state that the current Terraform template is using, then it is an absolute anti-pattern.

Instead, make the values you need to reference part of the outputs of the network module, then pass those values as inputs to the DB module.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @Mark B, I'll try and refactor this to not use data.terraform_remore_state.